# Perform a math operation on all numbers in a file

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a list of pixel values in a file, and need each to be half its current value. The pattern for the value is always `123px` where 123 varies drastically.

How can I half each pixel value?
I'm guessing `sed` will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `awk` instead of `sed`.

If your input file `file.dat` contains one entry per line this will work:

```
$ awk '{ print $1/2"px"}' file.dat
```

If you need more sophisticated math use `gawk` instead of `awk`.

Comment: Looking into the awk docs now, but each value has exists on a line with other info and another value, like this (it's CSS): `.sprite-v16   { background-position: -462px -2002px; }`

Comment: This is more complicated than your question made it seem. While looking around I came across http://www.issociate.de/board/post/461416/Math_in_sed/regexp_expression.html, but it needs some adijustments for your case. Since CSS can contain simple calculations you could just replace `ps` by `*0.5px` for the time being: `sed 's/px/\*0\.5px/g'`.